# Asp.Net web forms: "Parser Error Message: Could not load type" for pages inside folders

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a site. the default.aspx page in root folder is accessible but other pages inside folders throw  "Parser Error Message: Could not load type" error.

say:

http://behdoctor.ir/default.aspx is OK

but

http://behdoctor.ir/insurance_price_query_pages/default.aspx

or

http://behdoctor.ir/insurance_introduction_pages/default.aspx is not accessible.

do you know how can I overcome this problem?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you need to set up your sub folder as an application in IIS.

[image]

Comment: i dont have access to IIS. my site is hosted on a server with a plesk cpanel. is it possible to do so?

Comment: @Ali.Rashidi I'm sorry, I do not know anything about configuring Plesk. I would contact your host and ask them about it.

Comment: You can ask your hosting provider to convert it to application. It will fix your issue. In Plesk, you can also create it as virtual directory.